# Emulating ShowDialog functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, events, dialog, messagebox

I am writing an application (c# + wpf) where all modal style dialogs are implemented as a `UserControl` on top of a translucent grid covering the main `Window`. This means there is only one `Window` and it maintains the look and feel of all the firms applications.

To show a `MessageBox`, the syntax is as following:

```
CustomMessageBox b = new CustomMessageBox("hello world");
c.DialogClosed += ()=>
{
   // the rest of the function
}
// this raises an event listened for by the main window view model,
// displaying the message box and greying out the rest of the program.
base.ShowMessageBox(b);
```

As you can see, not only is the flow of execution actually inverted, but its horribly verbose compared to the classic .NET version:

```
MessageBox.Show("hello world");
// the rest of the function
```

What I am really looking for is a way to not return from `base.ShowMessageBox` until the dialog closed event has been raised by it, but I cant see how it is possible to wait for this without hanging the GUI thread and thus preventing the user ever clicking OK. I am aware I can take a delegate function as a parameter to the `ShowMessageBox` function which kind of prevents the inversion of execution, but still causes some crazy syntax/indenting.

Am I missing something obvious or is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfmodaldialog.aspx) article on CodeProject and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Creating_a_Modal_Custom_Dialog_Box) article on MSDN. The first article walks you through manually creating a blocking modal dialog, and the second article illustrates how to create custom dialogs.

Comment: The first article linked shows a perfect example of how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is by using a [DispatcherFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe.aspx) object.

```
var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
CustomMessageBox b = new CustomMessageBox("hello world");
c.DialogClosed += ()=>
{
    frame.Continue = false; // stops the frame
}
// this raises an event listened for by the main window view model,
// displaying the message box and greying out the rest of the program.
base.ShowMessageBox(b);

// This will "block" execution of the current dispatcher frame
// and run our frame until the dialog is closed.
Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up another message loop in the message box class. Something like :

```
public DialogResult ShowModal()
{
  this.Show();

  while (!this.isDisposed)
  {
    Application.DoEvents();
  } 

   return dialogResult;
}
```

If you look at Windows.Form in Reflector you will see it does something like this..

Comment: He's using WPF, not WinForms.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. WPF is completely different? Do windows no longer have message loops?

Comment: Never use solution like

`  while (!this.isDisposed)
  {
    Application.DoEvents();
  } 
`

It blocks UI or exhaust UI by DoEvents.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function into an iterator that returns an `IEnumerator<CustomMessageBox>`, then write it like this:

```
//some code
yield return new CustomMessageBox("hello world");
//some more code
```

You would then write a wrapper function that takes the enumerator and calls `MoveNext` (which will execute all of the function until the next `yield return`) in the `DialogClosed` handlers.

Note that the wrapper function would not be a blocking call.